Change columns count in bootstrap album
I use this example for my web application https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/album
It works fine but I need change columns count from 3 to 2. Is it possible?
My code:
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">

            <div id="swap-image-container" style="display: none;" class="col">
                <div class="card shadow-sm">
                    <img id="swap-image" class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="100%"/>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Swap image. Face replacement result.</p>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="enchanced-swap-image-container" style="display: none;" class="col">
                <div class="card shadow-sm">
                    <img id="enchanced-swap-image" class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="100%"/>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Enchanced Swap image. Face replacement result with post-processing.</p>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I tried changing columns count in bootstrap class names but it didn't change anything.

Could you please also provide me your CSS linked to this HTML file?

The file itself: https://github.com/qAqa1/FaceSwapStudio/blob/9e06aaf1c6a59d3db2e20d5c592646804ef39f0b/FaceSwapStudioWeb/FaceSwapStudioWeb/Views/Home/SingleImagesProcessing.cshtml The template (file will placed instead @RenderBody()): https://github.com/qAqa1/FaceSwapStudio/blob/9e06aaf1c6a59d3db2e20d5c592646804ef39f0b/FaceSwapStudioWeb/FaceSwapStudioWeb/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Just change the row columns number from 3 to 2:
row-cols-md-3 -> row-cols-md-2

or just remove it, so that you'll have two columns on all screens above small here:
<div class="container">
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 g-3">

see: Row columns
demo (using BS v5.0.2, note that you have latest version of the example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/album/):


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 g-3">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>




I didn't see any difference after trying this.

as you can see in the snippet, there are two columns. if your code doesn't have two columns, then you need to inspect it and see why (and rendered version, when you run the app). if you paste the template code as is, it also shows two columns..
